# Web API - custom routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have problem with creating appropriate routeTemplate for Web API.
Example request is going to look like this:

```
POST /mobile?command=doSomething?parameter1=value&parameter2=value HTTP/1.1
Host: {ENDPOINT}
Accept: application/json
```

I probably can use

```
routeTemplate: "{controller}"
```

and somehow handle it manually in controller, but it doesn't look like good solution.

I tried

```
routeTemplate: "{controller}?command={action}"
```

but i got ArgumentException, because routeUrl can't contain question marks.

What's the proper routeTemplate here?

Comment: Several questions occurred while reading your your post. 
1. Is it required for you to use the old style routing especially if you are the developer of the API?
2. Why do you want to make POST-s using query string?

Comment: I have no practical experience with APIs except writing one simple WCF service long time ago, so I appreciate suggestions. I'm limited to .NET 4, by old style routing you mean using command parameter or not using attribute routing? I received documentation with many sample POST requests like one above to implement. I can suggest doing it another way, but first I need to understand what is wrong with that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the controller is handling different POST requests, I would try setting it up like this:

```
"{controller}/{action}/{parameter1}/{parameter2}" // will hit url: mobile/MyActionMethod/2/3
```

the above route will hit a controller with the method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyActionMethod(HttpRequestMessage request, int parameter1, int parameter2)
```

If you don't want the parameters in the URL then either use a JObject to pass them and pull them from a dynamic, or pass model as a paremter.

```
"{controller}/{action}/"// will hit url: mobile/MyActionMethod

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyActionMethod(HttpRequestMessage request, Jobject data){//JObject requires Json.NET

dynamic json = data;
int parameter1 = json.parameter1;
int parameter2 = json.parameter2;
}
```

or using a model of

```
public class MyMode{
public int Parameter1{get;set;}
public int Parameter2{get;set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyActionMethod(HttpRequestMessage request, MyModel model){
    var parameter1 = model.Parameter1;
    var parameter2 = model.Parameter2;
}
```